# Does a Monk's Belt add to Unarmored Speed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk

I have seen several [1](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Ultimate_Monk_%283.5e_Optimized_Character_Build%29),[2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13/optimizing-a-dd-3-5-monk) places that state's the Monk's Belt increases Monk's Unarmored Speed Bonus.

A [Monk's Belt](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#beltMonks) is:

> This simple rope belt, when wrapped around a character’s waist, confers great ability in unarmed combat. The wearer’s AC and unarmed damage is treated as a monk of five levels higher. If donned by a character with the Stunning Fist feat, the belt lets her make one additional stunning attack per day. If the character is not a monk, she gains the AC and unarmed damage of a 5th-level monk. This AC bonus functions just like the monk’s AC bonus.

Does any one know why people are saying it increases speed bonus?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Because people on the Internet are frequently wrong.**

As you note, the [Monk's Belt](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#beltMonks) says specifically what it changes, and speed isn't one of them, though if someone wanted to house-rule that it did it wouldn't exactly break the game.

Comment: People on the Internet and elsewhere, too.

Answer (score 12):

**It's a common misconception**

The Monk's Belt does *not* add to Unarmored Speed, but a lot of people think it does during online discussions because of a common shorthand when talking about the Belt; specifically, people say it 'lets you buy five levels in Monk'. Because the Monk's Belt enhances so many other features of the Monk that most players/builds care about, it's easy to discuss it in that fashion - but it does lead to misconceptions.