# How many Astral Constructs may exist at one time, created from the same manifester?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

I can find nothing in the Expanded Psionics Handbook mentioning a limit on the number of astral constructs that can be manifested at one time.  The duration of the Astral Construct power is 1 round / level, so there is ample time while an astral construct exists to manifest multiple others.

However, in the Complete Psionic add-on book, under the description for the Skin of the Construct feat, there is a clear implication that there can be only one active astral construct at a time:

> This construct, once absorbed into your body, does not count against your limit of astral constructs crafted (in most cases you can have only one astral construct active at a time).

So where is the reference to a limit on active astral constructs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### *Expanded Psionics Handbook*: no limit

The original definition of *astral construct*, given in *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, has no limit on the number of astral constructs you could create, other than the limit on the number of power points you can spend in a day/the number of actions you can use before older constructs begin to expire.

*Expanded Psionics Handbook* is one of the most well-designed books for 3.5, widely acclaimed for solid and cohesive design.<sup>1</sup> 3.5 Psionics is an elegant system that provides a lot of important limitations that traditional spellcasting lacks. This makes it easier to use and more consistently balanced. It is also very popular, literally spawning an entire third-party publisher (Dreamscarred Press) to carry on its legacy, as well as a [massive homebrew effort to translate traditional spellcasting to psionic mechanics](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?194002-3-5-A-Translation-of-Vancian-Spellcasting-to-Psionic-Mechanics).

#### *Complete Psionics*: harsh limits

*Complete Psionics* rewrites a number of powers from *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, including *astral construct*, and includes this line:

> You can only have one astral construct shaped at a time.

No justification for this change is given, but several feats and a prestige class are offered to partially undo this nerf.

*Complete Psionics* is one of the most widely-panned books for 3.5. In contrast to *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, *Complete Psionics* is full bad ideas,<sup>2</sup> filler,<sup>3</sup> and complete disregard for the existing psionics system that had been in place.<sup>4</sup> And then there is the issue of the “errata” themselves: instead of properly publishing errata for *Expanded Psionics Handbook* for free on the Internet, Wizards of the Coast put “errata” into *Complete Psionics*. This has neither the support of the official rules, nor is it an appropriate way to errata things: if there were issues with *Expanded Psionics Handbook*, that should be in an errata for **that** book.

#### So who wins? *Expanded Psionics Handbook*

The official errata documents available on Wizards website explain the process of adjudicating between conflicting rule sources: the “primary” source wins. In the case of *astral construct*, the primary source is *Expanded Psionics Handbook*.

Note that this contradicts the FAQ, which claims the most recent version wins. However, the FAQ itself is now contradicting the errata documents – and the errata documents are the primary source on errata. Thus, the errata documents’ rule wins, and thus *Expanded Psionics Handbook* wins. The FAQ is **never** the primary source on any issue, and any contradiction between the FAQ and the published rules is, under the errata rules, officially to be decided in favor of the published rules. Since the FAQ **frequently** makes such contradictions, the FAQ is basically worthless, even for its stated goal of clarifying the rules (since they get the rules wrong so often that one can put little faith in those rulings).

#### This is a good thing: there were no problems with shapers under *Expanded Psionics Handbook*

The nerf to *astral construct* was utterly inappropriate. Shaper psions were an interesting option for players, but not one that itself caused problems. Far more powerful options are available – both to psions, and especially to other classes like clerics, druids, or wizards. But shapers were interesting and competent, and many found them a great deal of fun to play.

The *Complete Psionics* nerf kills that character concept. A solitary *astral construct* is extremely limited, and the feats and prestige classes used to partially undo that nerf are far too expensive. I could perhaps see playing a shaper-nerfed-by-*Complete Psionics* in an intentionally low-power game, but such a game should include *numerous* houserules limiting powers across many classes. *Complete Psionics*’s rule is not appropriate to a typical game of D&D.

So even if you don’t buy the errata argument – and I’ll freely admit, it’s pretty weak to claim that a published book is *wrong* when it says it is changing things – using *Complete Psionics* on this point is a bad idea for most games. I cannot more **strongly** recommend that *astral construct* be left alone, free to make as many constructs as you have time/power points for.

---

1. <sup>Excepting the soulknife; even the best books always have *something*. The soulknife is atrocious, even weaker than the [monk](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13/4563). Still, an overly-weak class is arguably superior to an overly-powerful one.</sup>
2. <sup>The divine mind is a psionic character – that is, a character who derives their magic from their inner power, from their own mind and soul – who can *fall* as a paladin can. The class is a complete travesty.</sup>

   <sup>A similar case is the anarchic initiate, a class that is all about infusing powers with chaos. You can enter with Wild Surge, and indeed, it improves and expands on the concept of Wild Surge. But it can alternatively be entered with the Overchannel feat, which psions can choose as a bonus feat, and either way it requires 8 ranks in Knowledge (the planes) – which psions get in class, but wilders don’t. Thus, the class that is dedicated to expanding on the wilder’s key class feature, is easier to enter and more effective for psions than it is for wilders.</sup>
3. <sup>There are a **ton** of feats in *Complete Psionic* that are literally</sup>

   > #### ____ Mind Blade
   >
   > When you reshape your mind blade, you can change it into a _____.
   >
   > **Prerequisite:** Ability to generate a mind blade, shape mind blade class feature.
   >
   > **Benefit:** Any time you wish to reshape your mind blade using your shape mind blade class feature, you can add the ______ to your shape repertoire. You are proficient with your ______ mind blade—you are treated as if you possess the feat ______ Weapon Proficiency (_____ mind blade). The weapon is sized appropriately for you and deals damage as a _____.

   <sup>It’s a disgusting waste of space and customer’s time and money.</sup>
4. <sup>Refers both to unnecessary nerfs like *astral construct*, as well as to completely inappropriate powers like *synchronicity*, and things like the divine mind. *Complete Psionics* is the source of **most** broken psionic tricks, and its material is just very poor in general.<sup>5</sup></sup>
5. <sup>Just to be fair to *Complete Psionics*, the ardent, soulbow, and Practiced Manifester are pretty solid. Those are literally the only good things I can think of from the book, though.</sup>

Comment: The errata argument is legit. Unsure what you mean by saying it's weak.  Do you mean that it's not commonly accepted?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer See the discussion in the linked question about *Rules Compendium*.

Comment: Errata is available, it was submitted to WotC, but didn't get posted on the website due to an oversight within the company due to various circumstances per the author of the book. People's opinions on the quality of the errata is as varied as on the book itself.

Comment: It seems to me the reason the unnecessary nerf was added to Astral Construct in Complete Psionics was to promote, perhaps unwarranted, the ectopic adept prestige class.

Answer (score 1):

## In Complete Psionic

The *astral construct* power was reprinted in the Complete Psionic.  The new version is very similar to the old one.  The main difference is:

> You can only have one astral construct shaped at one time.

The new version is on Complete Psionic p. 79.

I'm guessing that this was Wizards' way around their "don't errata anything without a reprint" policy, but there is nothing in either book that definitively says that you have to use the version printed in the Complete Psionic over the one in the Expanded Psionics Handbook.  The change isn't even listed in the errata for the Expanded Psionics Handbook.

In the end, which version of the power is going to be used in your game is up to your DM.  There are rules about which source has primacy over which other source, but those rules are not well known outside of DMs who have spent a lot of time on the internet.  One or the other might be 'correct' based on a legalistic interpretation of the primacy rules, but that doesn't change which one a particular DM wants to use.  If your DM likes the Complete Psionic, you probably can only summon 1 astral construct at a time.  If he doesn't, you can probably summon multiple.

Comment: +1 Mystery solved.  I'm curious why Wizards decided to change the power (in my opinion, rather severely).

Comment: There is nothing in either book that definitively says you have to use *Complete Psionic* because this is [stated in the FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/56815/4576) that tells us to interpret source rules to mean that "Unless stated otherwise, any time that a rule appears in two different sourcebooks (other than the *PH*, *DMG*, and *MM*), the most current sourcebook is considered correct and all previous sources are superseded." Thus, Complete Psionic's printing of options like *astral construct* is the "correct" printing. Many tables ignore Complete Psionic nerfs, however.

Comment: In the SRD, there is no limit on the power either.

Comment: The FAQ is wrong here, as it often is. The official errata rules are very clear on this point. The **primary source** wins, not the most recent. *Expanded Psionics Handbook* is the primary source for *astral construct*. This is analogous to the argument about [*Rules Compendium*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37466/4563), but where *Rules Compendium* is, for the most part, a well thought-out book, *Complete Psionics* is complete trash, written in part by someone with an avowed dislike of psionics.

Comment: Better, though I suspect you meant “the *errata* for the Expanded Psionics Handbook,” in that last line. Further, the lack of clarification about how to handle such contradictions makes this a weak answer, potentially misleading readers into thinking *Complete Psionics* is a worthy contender on this point.

Comment: *shrug*  I really don't have a dog in this fight.  I've only ever played with the 1 construct limit in place, and it didn't cause any problems.  No matter what legalistic interpretation of the 3.5 primacy rules you use, printed rules are printed rules, and are valid for use in games.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Not actually, most people who try to play by the rules obey the official errata, and many people who play the game use a variety of house rules and DM rulings as framework for the game in addition to correctly interpreted published rules to the exclusion of other published rules.  *Complete Psionics*, in particular, is generally disregarded by experts on the issue, but moreover your statement that jurisprudence indicates all printed rules are valid in all games is silly and patently false.