# What makes a good Prestige Class for a Monk?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, monk, prestige-class

As it says in the title, I'm asking for advice on which Prestige Class works best with the Monk. What I'm asking for, more specifically:

1. What Prestige Class has the best synergy?
2. That doesn't require multi classing in another base class.

Comment: Optimization questions require more information to answer: what does it mean to be the “best” as a monk? Are you looking to be mobile, a heavy-hitter, hard to hit, have mystical powers, or what? Note that monk is a very scattered class that can go lots of different ways, and most prestige classes will focus on one aspect. Also note that [monk is one of the weakest classes in the game](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13/4563), and in particular does almost-nothing on 3rd through 5th, which will be hard for a prestige class to fix at 6th.

Comment: That said, we definitely *can* make your monk the best monk they can be—as soon as you tell us what “best” means to you. You may also want to check out a search of [dnd-3.5e monk optimization](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e+monk+optimization) questions, though there are only a few. [dnd-3.5e monk prestige-class](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e+monk+prestige-class) also offers some stuff, as does [dnd-3.5e monk character-creation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e+monk+character-creation).